# How does one log all processes running on Mac OS X to a file

Tags: macos, logging, process, terminal, pid

In terminal, how would one take all the processes running on my Mac OS X 10.7 and save them to a text file (or CSV if possible) on their desktop?

I ran the following command in terminal and after 10 minutes of waiting for the command to run assumed it was not the right one:

```
$ top > /desktop/tmp/process.txt
```

I understand that there are many data-points that the $ top command displays for a single process, it would be great to capture processes in a CSV for easy importing into excel.  Would I need to specify which data-points I'd like to collect in my file?  Example would be:

- PID
- PPID
- Process Name
- User
- CPU Time
- Ports
- Threads

Thanks a bunch for any guidance here.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I am sort-of unsure on this question because the obvious answer is `ps`. For instance, the following will give you all processes run in a terminal and no terminal, by user:

```
ps -aux > /desktop/tmp/process.txt
```

There are tons of options for `ps`. Type the following into your terminal to find more options: `man ps`.

It doesn't run continuously like top, but there are variations, of course.